# SQL Sorting: ORDER BY with parameters

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-order-by, case

I am having trouble executing this statement.

What I am trying to achieve here is that my result will be sorted with a condition with the use of a parameter.

For example, I would like to sort the userName in ascending order, therefore, in my web application coding I have a parameter @condition, when it reads 'userName' the sql statement below executes.

The error is :

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date
```

It appeared 6 times.

I am not sure if CASE is used correctly.

The result I would like is that when a condition is being called and inserted to the @condition, it should sort the result of that specific condition.

The attributes in the database are declared in this way:

```
C.joinDate - DATE
C.userName - VARCHAR(20)
C.firstName - VARCHAR(20)
C.lastName -  VARCHAR(15)
C.contact - CHAR(8)
C.dob - DATE
C.userStatus - VARCHAR(8)
C.totalPoints - INT
R.resID - VARCHAR(8)
P.orderID - VARCHAR(8)
D.orderID - VARCHAR(8)
CR.securityCode - VARCHAR(10)
C.loginAttempted - INT



SELECT C.joinDate, C.userName, (C.firstName+' '+C.lastName) AS Name, 
 C.contact, C.dob, C.userStatus, C.totalPoints,  COUNT(R.resID) AS Res,
 COUNT(P.orderID) AS PreOrd, COUNT(D.orderID) AS DelOrd, 
 COUNT(CR.securityCode) AS Redeem, C.loginAttempted  FROM Customer C
 full join Reservation R  ON C.userID = R.userID  full join PreOrder P
 ON R.resID = P.ResID  full join DeliveryOrder D ON D.userID = C.userID
 full join CustomerRedemption CR ON CR.userID = C.userID WHERE
 (C.firstName+' '+C.lastName) LIKE '%%' and c.userName LIKE '%%' and
 c.contact LIKE  '%%' and c.userStatus LIKE '%%' GROUP BY C.joinDate,
 C.userName, (C.firstName+' '+C.lastName), C.contact, C.dob, 
 C.userStatus, C.totalPoints, C.loginAttempted HAVING C.userName IS NOT
 NULL ORDER BY          CASE 'userName'
                WHEN 'joinDate' THEN joinDate
                WHEN 'userName' THEN userName
                WHEN 'Name' THEN (C.firstName+' '+C.lastName)
                WHEN 'dob' THEN dob
                WHEN 'userSatus' THEN userStatus
                WHEN 'totalPoints' THEN totalPoints
                WHEN 'totalPoints' THEN totalPoints
                WHEN 'Res' THEN COUNT(R.resID)
                WHEN 'PreOrd' THEN COUNT(P.orderID)
                WHEN 'DelOrd' THEN COUNT(D.orderID)
                WHEN 'Redeem' THEN COUNT(CR.securityCode)
                END
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Regardless of database, if the result of the query is to be used outside of the database, by some type of client, DO NOT SORT in the database. It is so much less expensive to do it in the client.

Comment: @Darek That depends on far too many factors to provide a universal guideline.  Do you have a large dataset with pagination?  Sorting must be server side.  Do you have an index on the sort column?  Depending on the query, you may be able to get the data out already sorted at no additional cost.  Yes, there are some times when the sorting should be done or even must be done on the client, but we have to take each situation on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you order by a case statement all possible outputs of the case must be of the same type. You need to break your case statement down into multiple case statements.

Each case statement should return a single type and `NULL` for the else case. You can combine all those cases into one order by.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe want to try something like this:

```
CASE WHEN @condition = 'username' THEN username
     WHEN @condition ='joinDate' THEN joinDate
     WHEN @condition = 'userName' THEN userName
     WHEN @condition = 'Name' THEN (C.firstName+' '+C.lastName)
     WHEN @condition = 'dob' THEN dob
     WHEN @condition = 'userSatus' THEN userStatus
     WHEN @condition = 'totalPoints' THEN totalPoints
     WHEN @condition = 'totalPoints' THEN totalPoints
     WHEN @condition = 'Res' THEN COUNT(R.resID)
     WHEN @condition = 'PreOrd' THEN COUNT(P.orderID)
     WHEN @condition = 'DelOrd' THEN COUNT(D.orderID)
     WHEN @condition = 'Redeem' THEN COUNT(CR.securityCode)
     END
```

or as you had it would also be correct but with a small correction:

```
CASE @condition
     WHEN 'username' THEN username
     WHEN 'joinDate' THEN joinDate
     WHEN 'userName' THEN userName
     WHEN 'Name' THEN (C.firstName+' '+C.lastName)
     WHEN 'dob' THEN dob
     WHEN 'userSatus' THEN userStatus
     WHEN 'totalPoints' THEN totalPoints
     WHEN 'totalPoints' THEN totalPoints
     WHEN 'Res' THEN COUNT(R.resID)
     WHEN 'PreOrd' THEN COUNT(P.orderID)
     WHEN 'DelOrd' THEN COUNT(D.orderID)
     WHEN 'Redeem' THEN COUNT(CR.securityCode)
     END
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your issue is in your CASE statement. First off the parameter needs to be in the statement itself.

```
...
HAVING C.userName IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY 
CASE @condition
WHEN 'joinDate' THEN joinDate
...
```

You should also have an ELSE section at the end of the CASE statement.

See section C of the CASE page.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In a `case` statement, each `when` must return compatible types. In your case you want three case statements, one for string, one for numeric and one for date.

```
order by
  CASE @condition
      WHEN 'joinDate' THEN joinDate
      WHEN 'dob' THEN dob
  END,
  CASE @condition
      WHEN 'userName' THEN userName
      WHEN 'Name' THEN (C.firstName+' '+C.lastName)
      WHEN 'userSatus' THEN userStatus
  END,
  CASE @condition
      WHEN 'totalPoints' THEN totalPoints
      WHEN 'totalPoints' THEN totalPoints
      WHEN 'Res' THEN COUNT(R.resID)
      WHEN 'PreOrd' THEN COUNT(P.orderID)
      WHEN 'DelOrd' THEN COUNT(D.orderID)
      WHEN 'Redeem' THEN COUNT(CR.securityCode)
  END;
```

Or you can convert everything to text:

```
      WHEN 'joinDate' THEN to_char( joinDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd' )
```

Just be sure the form is such that lexical order is the same as date/numeric order.

Also, the `having` clause is for aggregate results. The `C.userName IS NOT NULL` test should be in the `where` clause as you are using that to filter the result set before any aggregate functions are even applied. An example of using `having` would be something like

```
having COUNT(P.orderID) > 0
```

This performs additional filtering *after* the aggregate functions have returned values.